# Why do two EV3 bricks have different power outputs?

Tags: ev3

I have two identical box designs with EV3 bricks.  When I upload the same programs to both, one moves about twice as fast as the other.

Is there a reason that this might be happening?  Is there anything I can do to update it?

Comment: Have you checked the batteries? Maybe one has almost-dead batteries?

Comment: I have fully charged both batteries and they are both reporting full batteries.  I will try to swap out the batteries but right now it's not easily accessible from the design I've got, so I was just curious if this was expected or not.

Comment: Can you post your program, or at least the part with the Move blocks?

Comment: It's noticeable on a standard steering block - say at 75 power and going for a few rotations - on one brick that move may take a second, on the other, 2 seconds. i'll run and time it later today and post specific times, wheel diameters and rotations.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with the ev3 bricks? Have you tried switching the motors? Maybe one is defective?

Comment: I didn't swap the motors, but if one of the motors was defective, on a tank steering block I would expect that if both motors were at the same power it would turn because one motor would be outputting power at a different level.  Given that it goes straight, it would mean that both motors are sending the same output.

Comment: Is it possible you have more tension or friction in one of the builds? I assume that you've got some gears, etc in there - are they all able to spin freely, or are some of them clamped a bit tighter? I agree this is probably unlikely based on your comment about "tank steering" as that would required the two sides to be equally stiff.

Comment: So it turns out the issue was a bad rechargeable battery pack.  When I replaced with fresh batteries the robot performed comparably to the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some possible reasons:

- A motor is defective
- One of the brick has lesser battery charge
- Firmware problem: make sure both bricks have latest firmware

Comment: it was the battery.